# AES256 ctr mode behavior on counter overflow/rollover

Tags: encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric

I am trying to understand the expected behavior of aes256 ctr mode when the counter rolls over..

for example given this value:

"iv": "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD",

Once the increment rolls, does it go to 0 or 1? RFC 3686 specifies that the block counter is to start at 1, but it doesn't really mention the behavior on a full rollover.  Is this documented anywhere?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: rfc3686 describes a CTR mode that does not match with popular implementations. It describes the IV as being made up of the nonce (32 bit), IV (64 bit) and counter (32 bit). All implementations that I know use the full 128 bit as the IV and start counting up. Perhaps that RFC is not the best way to evaluate rollover behavior. Anyway, this is better suited for [crypto.se].

Comment: Actually, [CTR mode is not safe to use the counter that much](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/85572/18298) even possible! In modern Cryptography, we don't use the CTR mode as it is. We use [AES-GCM](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/84359/18298) that uses CTR internally or better use AES-GCM-SIV to mitigate the nonce misuse issue.

Comment: @ArtjomB. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/71195/what-happens-if-you-increment-max-counter-in-aes-ctr/71196#71196

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this would be suited better on [crypto.se], but it has already been asked there (see comment with link)

Comment: @ArtjomB. Note that CTR mode as defined by NIST allows for quite a few methods of using the nonce / counter etc. It doesn't even define if it is big or little endian.

Comment: I took a look around and found an answer to my question.  Some asked a different question and somebodys answer answered my question..  Thanks!   .https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/71195/what-happens-if-you-increment-max-counter-in-aes-ctr/71196#71196